# Using x/time/rate.Limiter to determine N events happen within seconds

Tags: go

I'm not understanding how Go's [rate limiter package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate) works. I want to use it to determine if some timestamps happen within a certain amount of time.

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(100 * time.Second), 2)
    go func(limiter *rate.Limiter) {
        fmt.Println("Waiting!!")
            for {
                if !limiter.Allow() {
                    fmt.Println("Not allowed!!!")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("allowed!!")
                }
            }

        fmt.Println("done? blocked?")
    }(limiter)

    wg.Wait()
```

Why is "Not allowed!!!" being printed even though I haven't added anything to the rate limiter to determine if 2 events happen in certain amount of seconds?

Comment: because `burst=2` ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the `2` means `2` events should happen. How doI add things to the events then?

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter.ReserveN ?